Batch script for renaming all files, folders and subfolders
After extracting a zipped folder, all spaces (and other special characters like parenthesis) in all files and subfolders have been changed to URL encoding (e.g. spaces are now %20). I know it is possible to have a batch or powershell script to change it back to the actual special characters but I do not know how. Please help as I do not have any knowledge with this.
I have seen this solution and have used it successfully but it does not recurse through folders and subfolders, and only renames files not folders: https://superuser.com/questions/1029476/windows-batch-file-rename-to-replace-20-characters-with

To recurse through directories in PowerShell, look for Get-ChildItem -Recurse. Use the command help Get-ChildItem.

use [System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlDecode($String)
$Filename = 'Filname With Space and [special] Characters.what?'

$EncodedFilename = [System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode($Filename)

$EncodedFilename
# returns Filname+With+Space+and+%5Bspecial%5D+Characters.what%3F

$DecodedFilename = [System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlDecode($EncodedFilename)

$DecodedFilename
# returns Filname With Space and [special] Characters.what?

